# Python dictionary: set value as the key string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary and want to set one of the values as the key itself whilst initializing the dict. That is:

```
dummy = dict(
  Key1 = ["SomeValue1", "Key1"],
  Key2 = ["SomeValue2", "Key2"],
  )
```

Can this be done programmably? That is, to skip writing the key again and set something like `dummy.keys()[currentkeyindex]`.

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What do you mean with what output I do expect?

Comment: When you ask a question adding your input and your expected output from that input is useful.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the output is the same as the input, but I want that to happen **programmably** as indicated by the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> values = [
...     ["SomeValue1", "Key1"],
...     ["SomeValue2", "Key2"],
... ]
>>> {x[1]: x for x in values}
{'Key2': ['SomeValue2', 'Key2'], 'Key1': ['SomeValue1', 'Key1']}
```

Comment: Perfect, why is it on the opposite order?

Comment: @Werner, Python `dict` does not preserve key insertion order.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, that was exactly what I needed. In fact, I can't even accept your answer right now, since you guys answered it quite fast x)

Comment: @Werner, If you need to preserve order, use `collections.OrderedDict`: `import collectionsl collections.OrderedDict((x[1], x) for x in values)`

Comment: Yeah, I prefer to keep the order, although it doesn't matter…

Comment: @Werner, BTW, the given code in the question is not valid because the same keyword argument `Key2` repeated.

Comment: Just saw I forgot to change it to Key3…

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep track of items as well then use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict                                                                                                      
>>> output = defaultdict(list)
>>> values = [
        ["SomeValue1", "Key1"],
        ["SomeValue2a", "Key2"],
        ["SomeValue2b", "Key2"]
    ]
>>> for x in values:
...     output[x[1]].append(x)
... 
>>> output
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    'Key2': [['SomeValue2a', 'Key2'], ['SomeValue2b', 'Key2']], 
    'Key1': [['SomeValue1', 'Key1']]
})
```